# Why doesn't a Planck type derivation work for Hawking radiation?

Tags: black-holes, thermal-radiation, event-horizon, hawking-radiation

In Planck's derivation of black body radiation, Planck hypothesized $E=h\nu$ and got the correct black body radiation spectral function.

What is confusing me is why don't similar arguments work for Hawking radiation? Hypothesizing *discrete spectrum* of some physical quantity, maybe area of event horizon of order of Planck scale and then using it to derive the Hawking radiation.

Essentially above reasoning implies the fluctuation in the hypothesized discrete quantity leads to creation of quanta of Hawking radiation. In other words this quantity is hypothesized as microstate. Has this approach been addressed in the literature? If so what are its shortcomings?

Answer (score 0):

Black holes glow because the Unruh effect gives [a temperature proportional to the surface gravity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unruh_effect#Calculations). The role of discrete photons is to prevent the ultraviolet catastrophe, not to make black holes blackbodies in the first place. The resulting temperature-dependent spectrum, at the Unruh temperature, is just the Hawking spectrum.